# Getting this error when working with derived class "error: no suitable constructor found for Vehicle(no arguments)"

Tags: java

I'm working with 2 classes a parent class Vehicle and child class Car, each class has a copy constructor but I get the error

> ```
> >  "error: no suitable constructor found for Vehicle(no arguments)
> > public Car(Car c){
> >                  ^
> >     constructor Vehicle.Vehicle(int,String,Student) is not applicable
> >       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
> >     constructor Vehicle.Vehicle(Vehicle) is not applicable
> >       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)"
> ```

This is when using the copy constructor in the car class and not sure how to fix it.
The Vehicle class

```
public class Vehicle{

int cylinders;
String maker;
Student owner;

public Vehicle (int cylinders, String maker, Student owner){
this.cylinders = cylinders;
this.maker = maker;
this.owner = owner;
}

public Vehicle(Vehicle v){
this.cylinders = v.cylinders;
this.maker = v.maker;
this.owner = v.owner;
}
}
```

The Car class is as follows

```
public class Car extends Vehicle{
int passengers;
double carWeight;

public Car(int cylinders, String maker, Student owner, int passengers, double carWeight){
super(cylinders, maker, owner);
this.passengers = passengers;
this.carWeight = carWeight;
}

public Car(Car c){
this.cylinders = c.cylinders;
this.maker = c.maker;
this.owner = c.owner;
this.passengers = c.passengers;
this.carWeight = c.carWeight;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no empty constructor in `Vehicle` so a default `super()` in the `Car` copy constructor fails. You can use `super` instead. Like,

```
public Car(Car c){
    super(c.cylinders, c.maker, c.owner);
    this.passengers = c.passengers;
    this.carWeight = c.carWeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```java
public Car(Car c){
    super(c);
    this.passengers = c.passengers;
    this.carWeight = c.carWeight;
}
```

#### Why is there an error?

In your second constructor, an empty `super()` call will be implicitly made. Why? Since you do not call it explicitly and a `Vehicle` object is being constructed. You can add an empty constructor in the `Vehicle` class or use the snippet above.